# OnMessage event to STA thread

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, xmpp

i am using the Jabber.net library, in a vb/wpf application. i want to open a window when the OnMessage event raises, but i get an error:

*The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.*

this is my code:

```
Private Sub client_OnMessage(sender As Object, msg As protocol.client.Message) Handles client.OnMessage
    Debug.WriteLine("[Message Received] " & msg.From.User & ": " & msg.Body)
    client.Message(msg.From, "Message Reveived: " & msg.Body)
    Dim dialog As New AlertDialog(msg.From.User, "Test", msg.Body)
    dialog.Show()
End Sub
```

this is the line that goes into an error:

```
    Dim dialog As New AlertDialog(msg.From.User, "Test", msg.Body)
```

i can't use a background worker, since this is already in the wrong thread, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `InvokeControl` on your Client object to be any control on your form.  That will ensure that all of the JabberNet callbacks fire in the GUI thread for that control.